# kendo UI DropDownList behaves weird

Tags: html, kendo-ui, html-select

I have the following code. When fetching the value selected, it works fine. But if I try put the selected value in any condition, it falters. the code crashes.

```
var onAcctMgrSelect = function (e) {
    // access the selected item via e.item (jQuery object)
    ddAMList = $("#ddAM").data("kendoDropDownList");
    if (ddAMList.value() == "0")
        $("#btnSearch").attr("class", "k-button  k-state-disabled");
    else
        $("#btnSearch").attr("class", "k-button");
    ///alert(ddAMList.text()); 
    checkValidData();
};
```

DropDownlist Code is as below:

```
function loadAccountManagers() {
    $("#ddAM").kendoDropDownList({
        change: onAcctMgrSelect,
        dataTextField: "AcctMgrFullName",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
                schema: {
                    data: "d", // svc services return JSON in the following format { "d": <result> }. Specify how to get the result.
                    total: "count",
                    model: { // define the model of the data source. Required for validation and property types.
                        id: "Id",
                            fields: {
                                Id: { validation: { required: true }, type: "int" },
                                    AcctMgrFullName: { type: "string", validation: { required: true} }
                                    }
                           }
                        },
                transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "../services/Prospects.svc/GetAccountManagers", //specify the URL which data should return the records. This is the Read method of the Products.svc service.
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // tells the web service to serialize JSON
                    type: "GET" //use HTTP POST request as the default GET is not allowed for svc
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm basically trying to disable the submit button if the first item is selected (which is a blank item in my case with a value of '0').

Am I going wrong anywhere?  Please help!

Comment: Which line from the above code "crashes". How does it crash?

Comment: if (ddAMList.value() == "0") does not run at all and when I put that expression in a multi-condition expression, the whole expression crashes and does not resolve!

Comment: ???!!! Is the function called? If so, what is the value of evaluating `$("#ddAM").data("kendoDropDownList")` is it something other than `undefined`?

Comment: The above function is called when I select any item. the value and the text are properly set!

Comment: How does you drop-down definition look like? Can you include the code in the original question? There is something that I still do not understand from the above code.

Comment: Check your code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/PuBfF/1). Other than the fact that I've replaced the service by a function it is the same.

Comment: Well it works on my app too. My problem is that as soon as I try putting the ddAMList.value() == "0" inside any if block, it stops the if block processing. Do you think its wierd?
One more thing if I may add, if I select the drop down list first and then select other elements, everything works fine, but if I select any other element and have the above code in the if block, it fails!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30360/discussion-between-onabai-and-anshuman)